# Several Images in one msg, How can I do it?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code I have is the following:

> ```
>  
> int main(int argc, char **argv)
> {
>     ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
>         ros::NodeHandle nh;
>     ros::Rate loop_rate(100);       // Rate class instance. 
>     ImageManagmentStruct LeftCameraImageStructForGrid, RightCameraImageStructForGrid, KinectImageStructForGrid, KinectDepthImageStructForGrid;      
>     ImageManagmentStruct LeftCameraImageStructOneImage, RightCameraImageStructOneImage, KinectImageStructOneImage, KinectDepthImageStructOneImage;
>     
>     // Initializing the image/camera data structures.   
>     dataStructuresInitialization ( &LeftCameraImageStructForGrid, 
>                                    &RightCameraImageStructForGrid, 
>                                    &KinectImageStructForGrid,
>                                    &KinectDepthImageStructForGrid,
>                                    &LeftCameraImageStructOneImage,
>                                    &RightCameraImageStructOneImage,
>                                    &KinectImageStructOneImage,
>                                    &KinectDepthImageStructOneImage
>                                  );
>         
>     // GTK library initialization
>     gtk_init ( &argc, &argv );
> // Creating a top level window and connecting it to a sygnal.    
> createMainInterfaceWindow (); 
>
> // Creating a fixed container, which will hold all the widgets of the GUI.
> createFixedContainer ();
>
> // Creating a GtkGrid widget, which will contain all the images.
> createGtkTable ();
>
> // Attaching the created table to the Container.
> gtk_fixed_put (GTK_FIXED (pGlobalFixedContainer), pGlobalGtkTable, IMAGES_HORIZONTAL_PLACEMENT, IMAGES_VERTIACL_PLACEMENT);
>                         
> // Subscribing in order to receive images.
>
> //ros::Subscriber subLeft = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image> ("/republished/bb2/triclops/left/image_raw", 2, boost::bind(imageCallbackWrapper, _1, globalArrayOfImagesForGrid[0], globalArrayForSingleImages[0]));  
> // ros::Subscriber subRight = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image> ("/republished/bb2/triclops/right/image_raw", 2, boost::bind(imageCallbackWrapper, _1, globalArrayOfImagesForGrid[1], globalArrayForSingleImages[1])); 
> // ros::Subscriber subKinect = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image> ("/republished/usb_cam/image_raw", 2, boost::bind(imageCallbackWrapper, _1, globalArrayOfImagesForGrid[2], globalArrayForSingleImages[2]));
> // ros::Subscriber subKinectDepth = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image> ("/republished/usb_cam/image_raw", 2, boost::bind(imageCallbackWrapper, _1, globalArrayOfImagesForGrid[3], globalArrayForSingleImages[3]));
>
> //New Code, replacing the ros::Subscriber
> image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
> image_transport::Subscriber subLeft = it.subscribe("/republished/bb2/triclops/left/image_raw", 2, boost::bind(imageCallbackWrapper, _1, globalArrayOfImagesForGrid[0], globalArrayForSingleImages[0]));  
> image_transport::Subscriber subRight = it.subscribe("/republished/bb2/triclops/right/image_raw", 2, boost::bind(imageCallbackWrapper, _1, globalArrayOfImagesForGrid[1], globalArrayForSingleImages[1]));
> image_transport::Subscriber subKinect = it.subscribe("/republished/usb_cam/image_raw/", 2, boost::bind(imageCallbackWrapper, _1, globalArrayOfImagesForGrid[2], globalArrayForSingleImages[2]));
> image_transport::Subscriber subKinectDepth = it.subscribe("/republished/usb_cam/image_raw//republished/bb2/triclops/left/image_raw", 2, boost::bind(imageCallbackWrapper, _1, globalArrayOfImagesForGrid[3], globalArrayForSingleImages[3]));
>
> g_timeout_add(1000 / 100, do_ros, NULL);
>
> gtk_main();
>      
> if ( MY_FUNCTIONS_ENTRANCE_CONTROL ) { printf ("\033[01;33mExited from the main function normally.\033[01;37m\n" ); }
> return 0;
>
> }
> ```

I try to get the images, but I got none.
A simple receiver code, works fine with the Rosbag and one image, this code thosen't make the connections, can any one help me with this problem. pls.

Rodrigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242034/several-images-in-one-msg,-how-can-i-do-it?/) by [Rodrigo Lourenço](https://answers.ros.org/users/27752/rodrigo-louren%C3%A7o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2016-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rodrigo Lourenço](https://answers.ros.org/users/27752/rodrigo-louren%C3%A7o/) on 2016-08-19**:
Sorry my mistake, I forgot to show do_ros function.

gboolean do_ros ( gpointer data )
{

```
// Showing the main window, with the attached image.
if ( GTK_IS_WIDGET (globalTopLevelWindow) )
{

    gtk_widget_show_all ( globalTopLevelWindow );       

}

if (ros::ok())
{

    ros::spinOnce();
```

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-08-19**:
can you put some `std::cout` just before `ros::spinOnce()` to confirm that it gets called?

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-08-19**:
I also find the names of the topics you subscribe to rather strange. run `rostopic list` and check whether it outputs those same topic name exactly (slashes matter).

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-08-19**:
Also check whether there is some data on those topics. `rostopic echo --noarr /republished/usb_cam/image_raw//republished/bb2/triclops/left/image_raw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After changing from virtual machine to PC, the problem was solved.

The program runs as it should.

---

Originally posted by [Rodrigo Lourenço](https://answers.ros.org/users/27752/rodrigo-louren%C3%A7o/) with karma: 61 on 2016-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0